# Transfer data from one SQL Server table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, transfer, ssms

For example I have one SQL Server database that contains a table

```
Id          Address
1  England,London,someaddress
2  Germany,Berlin,someaddress2
```

And I have another SQL Server database that contains following table with scheme

```
 Id  Country City Address
```

I need transfer data from first database to second. Like this.

```
id  Country    City    Address
 1  England   London   someaddress
 2  Germany   Berlin   someaddress2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings This article should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Are you asking how to split a string in TSQL? If so, it has been asked [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tsql+split+string) already.

Comment: Has your question been answered? Or do you require more help?

Comment: My question hasn't been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a `User Define Function` that detect `Country` , `City`, `Address` by Splitting and than insert into second table.

Split Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (id int , items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int
    declare @id int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    set @id = 1
    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
        begin
            insert into @temptable(id, Items) values( @id , @slice)       
            set @id = @id + 1
        end

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

then use in Insert Query like this :

```
INSERT INTO NewTbl
SELECT .... , 
     (SELECT ITEMS FROM dbo.Split(Address) where id = 1) as Country,
     (SELECT ITEMS FROM dbo.Split(Address) where id = 2) as City,
     (SELECT ITEMS FROM dbo.Split(Address) where id = 3) as Address,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to actually move the data.

1.) Linked Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

2.) OpenRowSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

3.) Replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Depending on your needs you need to choose the best one for you.

If you want the data from your second database to be accessable in your original databse, in the same way as it's own data, for queries, stored procedures...etc have a look at Linked Servers.

If you want a one off access to data have a look at OpenRowSet.

If you have the same table on both databases and want to keep that data in sync automatically I would look at Replication. You can set up your own replication stored procedures that can perform custom logic, like the split.

You then can impliment the split as noted in the other answer to split your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy data from one server to another database server .then you must make linked server between them.

and execute like following query.

```
insert into [127.234.11.50].[cgwssitws].dbo.tbl_ws_hotelier(paramid,hotelid,paramname,paramvalue)
select paramid,hotelid,paramname,paramvalue from [126.32.22.30].[CGWS_Hotel].dbo.tbl_param where hotelid='22'
```